# Help! Best token path, in case of uniswap v2

Tags: solidity, tokens, uniswap

I'd like to know if there exists a function or method to calculate the best token trading path in Uniswap v2.

I think in uniswap v3, they provide function that gives us the best trading path.

But in version 2, which function do I have to use?

If such function doesn't exist, what algorithm should I use?

I found several projects in github.com, but they don't make sense and so complicated.

Plz anybody who knows, help me!!!
Any idea, any advice is welcome.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the smart-order-router: https://github.com/Uniswap/smart-order-router

I have a working example that I use in Uniswap Discord, this is a very base code

**working with the smart router / Auto Router SDK**
here is a working version that I have modified to make work ( This is setup to test on a mainnet fork, however it's using live data
(as the AlphaRouter is only for mainnet live so the live data and the
fork data will change with time and cause trade errors, so reset fork
before using)

to make main net only take out local provider and change all providers to main net provider.

The Alpha auto Router is using the New uniswap V3v2 router @ 0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45

USE WITH CAUTION, I'M NOT PERFECT AND GUARANTEE NOTHING : Check slippage and all variables as this is only an EXAMPLE

This is built As a TOKEN to TOKEN  Exact_Input swap with WETH deposit of 1 ETH.
To use ETH you can remove Weth deposit and token in approval and use the BigNumber.from(typedValueParsed) as the value of the transaction instead of 0

As I don't know EtherJS to well the Gas Price and Gas Limit for the Deposit and approval is a flat 100 gwei & 300k Limit, and should be modified for current network gas price and estimated gas Limit. (if anyone has that code ping me and I'll add, if I don't get to it first)

```
import { AlphaRouter } from '@uniswap/smart-order-router'
import { Token, CurrencyAmount } from '@uniswap/sdk-core'
import { JSBI, Percent } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";


const V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45";

const TokenInput = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

const TokenOutput = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";


const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/");
const web3 = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");

const privateKey = "0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80";
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey,web3);
const address = wallet.address;

import * as fs from 'fs';

let UniV3RouterAbi = fs.readFileSync('NewUniRouter.json');
const V3routerAbi = JSON.parse(UniV3RouterAbi);

let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('ERC20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

let WETHAbij = fs.readFileSync('WETHAbi.json');
const WETHAbi = JSON.parse(WETHAbij);

async function log(inpt){
    console.log(inpt);
    console.log("");
}

async function TokBal(tokens){
    var ERC20contract =  new ethers.Contract(tokens, ERC20, web3);
    var myERC20bal = await ERC20contract.balanceOf(wallet.address);
    return myERC20bal;
}

async function Deposit(amt){
    var WethC =  new ethers.Contract(TokenInput, WETHAbi, web3);
    var datac = await WethC.populateTransaction["deposit"]();
    var ncn = await wallet.getTransactionCount();

    const transaction = {
      data: datac.data,
      nonce: ncn,
      to: TokenInput,
      value: BigNumber.from(amt),
      from: wallet.address,
      gasPrice: '0x174876e800',
      gasLimit: '0x493e0',
    };

    const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
    const txHash =  await web3.sendTransaction(signedTx);
    log(txHash.hash);
}

async function Approve(Toked, amt){
    var WethC =  new ethers.Contract(Toked, ERC20, web3);
    var datac = await WethC.populateTransaction["approve"](V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amt);
    var ncn = await wallet.getTransactionCount();

    const transaction = {
      data: datac.data,
      nonce: ncn,
      to: Toked,
      value: BigNumber.from("0"),
      from: wallet.address,
      gasPrice: '0x174876e800',
      gasLimit: '0x493e0',
    };

    const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);
    const txHash =  await web3.sendTransaction(signedTx);
    log(txHash.hash);
    var appFor = await WethC.callStatic.allowance(wallet.address, V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
    log("Approved : "+appFor.toString());
}


const router = new AlphaRouter({ chainId: 1, provider: web3Provider });
const WETH = new Token(
  router.chainId,
  '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  18,
  'WETH',
  'Wrapped Ether'
);

const USDC = new Token(
  router.chainId,
  '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
  6,
  'USDC',
  'USD//C'
);

const typedValueParsed = '1000000000000000000';
const wethAmount = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(WETH, JSBI.BigInt(typedValueParsed));

const IO = "Exact_Input"
const TradeType = IO == "Exact_Input" ? 0 : 1;


const route = await router.route(
  wethAmount,
  USDC,
  TradeType,
  {
    recipient: wallet.address,
    slippageTolerance: new Percent(5, 100),
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now()/1000 +1800)
  }
);

var Ebal = await web3.getBalance(wallet.address);
log("Wallet Balance : "+Ebal.toString());

var tbal = await TokBal(TokenOutput);
log("Token Out Balance : "+tbal.toString());

await Deposit("1000000000000000000");
await Approve(TokenInput,"1000000000000000000");
var tbalW = await TokBal(TokenInput);
log("Token In Balance : "+tbalW.toString());

log(`Quote Exact In: ${route.quote.toFixed(wethAmount.currency === WETH ? USDC.decimals : WETH.decimals)}`);
log(`Gas Adjusted Quote In: ${route.quoteGasAdjusted.toFixed(wethAmount.currency === WETH ? USDC.decimals : WETH.decimals)}`);


var nc = await wallet.getTransactionCount();


const transaction = {
  data: route.methodParameters.calldata,
  nonce: nc,
  to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
  value: BigNumber.from(0),
  from: wallet.address,
  gasPrice: BigNumber.from(route.gasPriceWei),
  gasLimit: BigNumber.from(route.estimatedGasUsed).add(BigNumber.from("50000")),
};


const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);


const PretxHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(signedTx);


const txHash =  await web3.sendTransaction(signedTx)
log(txHash.hash);

var Ebal = await web3.getBalance(wallet.address);
log("Wallet Balance : "+Ebal.toString());

var tbal = await TokBal(TokenOutput);
log("Token Out Balance : "+tbal.toString());

var tbalW = await TokBal(TokenInput);
log("Token In Balance : "+tbalW.toString())
```

;

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Some problems are remaining for me. For example, smart order router can be used with uniswap v3, I think right? I wanna how to calculate token path in v2. Can I use smart-order-router with uniswap v2?

Comment: Gladly.
The Auto Router is designed to look for best price between V2 and V3